# $\mathbb{P}(A_1)≤\mathbb{P}(A_1)$ in Boole's inequality ($n=1$) proof?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, probability-inequalities

Why does [this proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boole%27s_inequality#Proof) use $≤$ in the $n=1$ (induction base case) case for Boole's inequality, when in fact it's an equality? That is, why claim, $\mathbb{P}(A_1)≤\mathbb{P}(A_1)$, when it should be a "$=$"?

The induction base case generally should be such that it's a "step" that can be generalised to $n$. The $n+1$ case uses a more sophisticated reasoning to display that there's really a "$\le$".

Comment: It's an induction argument.

Comment: @JohnK Yes, but is it valid?

Comment: Are you asserting that the claim $P(A_1) \leq P(A_1)$ is _false_ for some choices of event $A_1$?

Comment: In a proof by induction that $\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^n i = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$, why does it say that for $n=1$, $$\sum_{i=1}^n i~\text{equals} ~ 1~\text{which is of the form}~ \frac{n(n+1)}{2} = \frac{1(1+1)}{2}$$ and so the base case is established instead of just saying that for $n=1$, $\sum_{i=1}^1 = 1= n$ and so the base case is established? Surely it is unnecessary to include that pesky $\frac{1+1}{2}$ which everybody knows has value $1$?

Comment: Btw, even if the question was "simple". I see no reason to down vote, without voting to close.

Comment: This strikes me as a reasonable question. I think it's OK for someone not to understand the method of proof by induction. I don't see a need to close or for downvotes here.

Answer (score 5):

Note that the statement in the proof is true. Your statement that $P(A_1)=P(A_1)$ is also true and is stronger than the statement in the proof. However, the method of proof they used is induction.

In an induction proof, one states the "base case" (here it's $n=1$), then assumes it to be true for $n$, then proves that if it is true for $n$, then it is true for $n+1$.

It doesn't make sense to write $P(A_1)=P(A_1)$ as the base case because, although that is correct, that does not flow with the argument made. The proof attempts to show that the probability of the union of a finite collection of events is less than or equal to the union of the probabilities of those events. The proof is not attempting to establish equality, so to start your proof by establishing equality in the base case is an illogical and inappropriate step.

Comment: "... that does not flow with the argument made.". Which is why I'm asking. Why does it not state what's really correct (=), but rather "implicates" (=) by (≤). It's like syntactic sugar.

Comment: I think you're missing the forest for the trees here. The *only* goal of the proof is to prove that one quantity is less than or equal to the other quantity regardless of $n$. By induction, the author shows that one quantity is less than or equal to the other for $n=1$, then shows if it holds for $n=k$ that it holds for $n=k+1$. By writing $P(A_1)=P(A_1)$, the proof would flow more poorly and it would be less clear what the goal is, as the base case would show an equality whereas the goal is to establish an inequality - literally, Boone's inequality.

Comment: I understand your concern that the proof uses a slightly weaker condition here, but in terms of what makes the proof as clear and understandable as possible, I absolutely agree that the author should write $P(A_1)\leq P(A_1)$ instead of using an equality. I believe an equality makes things less clear and more confusing to the reader.

Answer (score 1):

Because the implication step supposes that $P(\cup_{i=1}^n A_i) \leq \sum_{i=1}^n P(A_i)$ for some $n$ which becomes $P(A_1) \leq P(A_1)$ for $n = 1$.  The author could have said $P(A_1) = P(A_1)$ if they wanted to (but only because this *implies* $P(A_1) \leq P(A_1)$, mind you), but it's more clear if you write the base case in exactly the same form as the implication step.